# Installer won't remove windows service

Tags: .net, windows-services, installation, setup-deployment

When I try to install over a previous version I get the error "The specified service already exists"

I stop the service before the installation and the services.msc snap-in is closed also.

I use a visual studio setup and deployment project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually uninstall the service first, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd8zc8ha(VS.80).aspx